@Class needs function but when add more than 0 parameters crashing
I'm coding a logger in python and right now I'm working on a logic which catches an unexpected error of a function. This is already working correctly, but now I wanted that there is an argument for a file path, to set up a log file. This is my code for an example usage:
@Logger.catch(file_path='tests/example.log')
def example_function():
    """
    Not working function, because of division by zero
    """
    var1 = 5
    var = 0

    result = var1 / var
    print(result)

And this is the catch function in a Logger class:
class Logger():
    def catch(func, file_path=None):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
                traceback_info = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
                line = traceback_info[-1][1]
                file = traceback_info[-1][0]
                function_name = traceback_info[-1][2]

                Logger.error(log_msg=str(e), highlighting=True, print_out=True, line=[line, file, function_name], file_path=file_path)
        
        return wrapper

The error I'm getting is this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zlelo/Documents/Git/Logproj/examples.py", line 20, in <module>
    @Logger.catch(file_path='tests/example.log')
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Logger.catch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'

Thanks for any help, cya!

Does this answer your question? Decorators with parameters?

To fix the issue you must set the catch method as static, and format it something like this:
class Logger:
    @staticmethod
    def catch(file_path=None):
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                // your try code goes here
            return wrapper
        return decorator

You can see more details here.
